# Maven best-practice regarding version number after project fork

Tags: maven

I know maven is very opinionated and there's always a path-of-least-resistance answer to most question. Is there one for this case:
What's the standard practice with an artifact's version after the original artifact is forked and the `groupId` and `artifactId` are changed?
In other words, this being the original pom *GAV*

```
<groupId>org.apache.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>some-project</artifactId>
<version>2.3.4</version>
```

What should be the version in my new pom

```
<groupId>com.example.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>some-bar-project</artifactId>
<version>???</version>
```

On one hand, it could be 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT to make it clear that the fork happened at 2.3.X. The problem is that if the original project evolves, now there's two 2.4.X, which could cause confusion.
On the other, one could reset the version as if it was a brand new artifact and start at 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. In this case the info about the code's origin can be documented on the VCS

The forked version will probably not be released to the public

Answer (score 1):

I would have though avoiding a fork would be best practice, however if you want to preserve the original version say `2.3.4` you could make it

```
<version>2.3.4-1.0</version> <!-- or --->
<version>2.3.4_1.0</version> <!-- or --->
<version>2.3.4.1.0</version>
```

To highlight this is your `1.0` version of the `2.3.4` fork.

What I use is

```
<version>2.3.4a</version>
<version>2.3.4b</version>
```

etc.

I would consider keeping the java `package` and `groupId.artifactId` the same.